# Duplicate markers in SitesOverlay

Tags: android, marker

Once again I seek the wisdom of my betters...

I'm working on an Android app that uses Google Maps and programmatically puts markers on the map based on status info from a file read from the web.

The problem I have is that each marker is drawn twice.  Once in the right spot and once a little below (the top line of the second marker is in line with the bottom of the first marker).

```
private class SitesOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private List<OverlayItem> items=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Drawable marker=null;

    public SitesOverlay(Drawable marker) {
        super(marker);
        this.marker=marker;

        try {
            data = getData();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            //
        }

        if (!data.equals("")) {
            String[] msg = data.split(NEWLINE);

            for (Integer i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                items.add(new OverlayItem(
                        getPoint(lat.get(suburb), lng.get(suburb)),
                        msg[i], msg[i]));
            }
        }

        populate();
        map.postInvalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return(items.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,
                boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
        //boundCenterBottom(marker);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            items.get(i).getSnippet(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        map.getController().setZoom(16 + zoomModifier);
        return(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return(items.size());
    }
}
```

However, the second marker only becomes evident if I uncomment the boundCenterBottom(marker) in the draw function.

I've been trying to workout what is placing the second marker for days.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

EDIT:  I forgot to mention that if I touch the screen the marker that is *not* boundCenterBottom disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally worked out what was wrong.

Change

```
public SitesOverlay(Drawable marker) {
    super(marker);
    this.marker=marker;
```

to

```
public SitesOverlay(Drawable marker) {
    super(marker);
    boundCenterBottom(marker);
```